# Set background image by week day and time using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following javascript to display a different image depending on the time of day:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
if (n > 19 || n < 6)
  // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
  document.body.className = "night";
else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
  // If time is between 4PM – 7PM sunset theme to ‘body’
  document.body.className = "sunset";
else
  // Else use ‘day’ theme
  document.body.className = "day";
});
```

http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kdDBL

However I need to define the background image by a day of the week as well.

So for example Monday, times between 6am - 12pm show an open image and 12pm -6am show close image then Tuesday 6am - 4pm show an open image and 4pm-8am show a close image. As you can see from the example each day has different opening and closing times. So each day of the week need to be defined in the javascript.

I've played around using the following javascript and defined each image and time under each day, but cannot seem to get it working:

```
var days = [
'SUN', //Sunday starts at 0
'MON',
'TUE',
'WED',
'THU',
'FRI',
'SAT'
];
```

Anyone who can help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to change a picture (or banner) depending on the time of the day. Very simple to use!

**Source Code:**

Paste this source code into the designated areas.

**External file:**

Paste this code into an external JavaScript file named: timePictureChange.js

```
/* This script and many more are available free online at
The JavaScript Source!! http://www.javascriptsource.com
Created by: Anonymous | http://musikimiz.googlepages.comLicensed under: Creative Commons License
 */

function pixTimeChange() {
  var t=new Date();
  var h = t.getHours();
  var r1="pic1.gif";
  var r2="pic2.gif";
  var el=document.getElementById('myimage');

  // See the time below. Note: The time is in 24 hour format.
  // In the example here, "7" = 7 AM; "17" =5PM.
  el.src = (h>=7 && h<17) ? r1 : r2;
}

// Multiple onload function created by: Simon Willison
// http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  pixTimeChange();
});
```

**Head**

Paste this code into the HEAD section of your HTML document.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="timePictureChange.js"></script>
```

**Body**

Paste this code into the BODY section of your HTML document.

```
<img src="" id="myimage" alt="time of day">
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

you can create a Date object with your specified date/time (e.g. var d = new Date('June 18, 2011 21:00:00');) and you can then compare the current date with your specified date when the page loads:

```
var d = new Date('September 25, 2014 23:23:00');
var current = new Date();
if(current > d) {
    document.getElementById("imageID").src = "newImage.png";
}
```

You can see an example of this here. (Comment out the first line, and comment in the second line to see the difference of future and past dates).

Comment: Hi E11Digital Multimedia Services. Unfortunately this is not the solution i'm looking for. I do not want to define a specific date i.e. September 25, 2014, 23:23:00. I need it to know whether it's Monday, Tuesday… then look at the times from my javascript then select which image to show.

You may be thinking something different. Are you able to fork the CodePen and show me how you would implement it to my original javascript as they would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there there are no brackets.

Then with the day modify if for your scope

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var day = weekday[d.getDay()];


        var n = d.getHours();



        if ((n > 19 || n < 6)&&(day==1))  {
          // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
        ;
          document.body.className = "night";
        }
        else if (n > 16 && n < 19){
          // If time is between 4PM – 7PM sunset theme to ‘body’

           document.body.className = "sunset";
        }
        else{

          // Else use ‘day’ theme
           document.body.className = "day";
        }
    });
```